# Best way to find similar elements in big array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, search

I have a string array of **one million** phone numbers and I wanna find those numbers which are similar in four last digits. For example:

```
9031017575
9031139446
9031507575
9013009446
9023027575
9012204000
```

Would be:

```
9031017575
9031507575
9023027575
9031139446
9013009446
```

Unique numbers which are similar in four last digits are listed.

```
string[] Numbers = File.ReadAllLines(NumbersFilePath);
List<string> SimilarNumbers = new List<string>();
List<string> DissimilarNumbers = new List<string>();
```

I've used loop-in-loop to compare all elements with each other and Regex to capture four last digits(which I wanna forget this algorithm and go through a modern, faster and easier one!).

Comment: Apparently you also wanna do this without research or writing code?  Just copy and paste?

Comment: sorting the reversed numbers and doing a walk?

Comment: I hope that you aren't writing software to spoof phone numbers and robo-call similar numbers with, because that's not cool.

Comment: Try following :             string[] input = {"9031017575", "9031139446","9031507575","9013009446","9023027575","9012204000"};

            var groups = input.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(x.Length - 4)).ToList();

Comment: @Plutonix no, a help is enough. a clue to a method or efficient algorithm.

Comment: @Sam no, we wanna sort our text database of numbers. goal is to group same numbers and sell them on a valid and famous website in country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] numbers = {"9031017575",
                    "9031139446",
                    "9031507575",
                    "9013009446",
                    "9023027575",
                    "9012204000"};

var similars = numbers.GroupBy(x => x.Substring(x.Length - 4))
                       .Where(g=>g.Count()>1)
                       .SelectMany(x => x)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: can I have one more question in this case?